# Managed package licensing

Tags: managed-package, licenses, lma

I have a managed package that would be used by System administrators and Sales Managers. However, Sales Reps and AEs would indirectly be referenced by the app for reading attributes off of them.

I want to create a per user license model for the app and want to include admins, sales managers, reps and AEs. I'm not sure how to enforce licensing for the reps/AEs since they are just referenced by the app and do not need the app to be explicitly installed for them.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A license allows the currently running user to use an app. Any user can be referenced normally (e.g. a custom lookup to a user), but they will be unable to query or modify the data that points to their user record. So, just like any other app, your licensing should be set for the number of users that will actually need the license attached to their user record to use the app.